# upload_max_filesize not changing even after modifying php.ini

Tags: mysql, file-upload, upload, phpmyadmin

Perhaps this issue arises due to the version I am using:
**PHP Version 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10**

I simply want to upload a larger file size via PHPMyAdmin.  In my PHPINFO page it displays `upload_max_filesize = 2M`.  I have changed the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` to `upload_max_filesize = 100M` and still do not see the changes in the PHPINFO page, even after a restart of server.

Is there a MYSQL Query I can run to update this perhaps?  I do not have a .htaccess file I looked for it.

Comment: And Additionally you need to restart your Apache server than only it will apply to the application.

Answer (score 3):

The line should read:

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

not

```
upload_max_filesize: 200M
```

In addition, you need to set `post_max_size` to an appropriate level - greater than `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` reads correctly as you stated, sorry it just wasn't formatted correctly in question.  I will try the `post_max_size` change when DB manager is available.

Comment: `post_max_size` is still reading `8M` instead of the ungodly large number I put in to see if it worked (`300M`).  I have verified that the Loaded Config Files are pulling from this php.ini as well.  Our IT MGR and I are very perplexed now

Answer (score 0):

If we run in the console the following:

```bash
php -r "echo phpinfo();" | grep max
```

Of course, we can only see the final configurations that apply.

**But** the "`.../apache2/php.ini`" file does ONLY apply to your web-site, not your console.

Where said file's path may be one of below:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
```